# NSString to NSURL returns false

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurl, percent-encoding

I have a URL which is in a string: `http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=is&c=23&pl=VAST&pli=10226041&PluID=0&pos=6670&ord=%5B1423164382.84%5D&cim=1`

I am trying to convert that string to `NSURL`.

I've tried several things, which are:

```
NSString *encodedString = [@"http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=is&c=23&pl=VAST&pli=10226041&PluID=0&pos=6670&ord=%5B1423164382.84%5D&cim=1" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
```

When I follow the URL object with a breakpoint it assigns 0 => false.

What should I do to convert that string to `NSURL`?

Comment: Semantically speaking, it's actually assigning `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

The parameters in your given URL string are already URL encoded. So:

```
NSString *string = @"http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=is&c=23&pl=VAST&pli=10226041&PluID=0&pos=6670&ord=%5B1423164382.84%5D&cim=1";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
// url is not nil
```